# Spring batch throws exception upgrading to 3.0.0.RELEASE from 2.1.8.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch, spring-integration

Greetings and Happy Friday: 
The below issue is bothering me on the verge of weekend... this seems to be version related as the Spring Batch programs are failing just after I pushed in changes from another branch with Spring version 3.0.0.RELEASE and respective schema changes. For better readability on [drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxBW_emlwj6NTnJZU3hwX3JQbVU&usp=sharing).

**Old working configuration**

--- pom.xml ---

```xml
<spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.integration.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
<spring-security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
<spring.batch.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
```

--- job.xml ---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="batch-jobs.xml"/>

    <batch:job id="responseFileReaderJob">
        <batch:step id="dailyRRJob">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="dailyRRReader" writer="dailyRRCRDBWriter" processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10"/>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
</batch:job>

</beans>
```

---

**NEW configuration that fails**

--- pom.xml ---

```xml
<spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.integration.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
<spring-security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
<spring.batch.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
```

--- job.xml ---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="batch-jobs.xml"/>
    <batch:job id="responseFileReaderJob">
        <batch:step id="dailyRRJob">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="dailyRRReader" writer="dailyRRCRDBWriter" processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10"/>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
</batch:job>

</beans>
```

--- batch-job.xml ---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd        
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd         
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd         
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd         
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- configuration to load  JobLauncherTestUtils -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils"/> 

    <tx:annotation-driven  mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Test class:**

```
package com.chofac.mint.batch;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfigurationAttributes;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;


@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml","classpath:META-INF/spring/mexResponseJob.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class mexResponseReaderJobTest {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(mexResponseReaderJobTest.class);
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher launcher;
    @Autowired
    private Job job;
    private JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();

    //@Ignore
    @Test
    public void testDBtoFlatFileJob() throws Exception {

        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        sw.start();
        JobExecution execution =launcher.run(job, jobParameters);
        logger.info("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        sw.stop();
        logger.info(">>> TIME ELAPSED:" + sw.prettyPrint());
    }
}
```

**Partial error log:**

```
2014-06-27 17:39:04,093 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider#773c550f': [dailyRegistryRejectCardRefresherDBWriter] 
2014-06-27 17:39:04,094 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'appConfig' 
2014-06-27 17:39:04,094 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'rldataSource'
2014-06-27 17:39:04,094 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' 
2014-06-27 17:39:04,094 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'persistenceUnit' 
2014-06-27 17:39:04,094 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing 
2014-06-27 17:39:04,095 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'
2014-06-27 17:39:04,095 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScopeConfiguration'
2014-06-27 17:39:04,095 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@778b3fee] to prepare test instance [com.chofac.mint.batch.MexResponseReaderJobTest@7786df0f]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)     
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)  
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)    
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)  
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)     
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)    
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]:
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
Factory method [public org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b02b9c89 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository    
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
Factory method [public org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b02b9c89
cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 42 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b02b9c89
cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository   
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54bada31.jobRepository(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:59)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54bada31.CGLIB$jobBuilders$7(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54bada31$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$61b95431.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54bada31.jobBuilders(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 43 more 2014-06-27 17:39:04,106 [main] DEBUG
org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener
- After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@1f25fefa testClass = MexResponseReaderJobTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null],
testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration =
[MergedContextConfiguration@379e8f17 testClass =
MexResponseReaderJobTest, locations = '{classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml, classpath:META-INF/spring/mexResponseJob.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

Tried the [solution mentioned here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/112513-jobrepository-is-mandatory) as this seems similar and my invoking class as below, but the same error.

```
public class MexRequestGeneratorJobTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml","classpath:META-INF/spring/mexRequestJob.xml");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("jobProcessor");
        JobLauncher launcher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("mexdb2FileJob");
        try{
            JobExecution jobExecution = launcher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Could you please provide me some clue as what is the way to fix this issue. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Are you injecting a property where target type is mapjobrepo instead of its interface into jobBuilders?

Comment: Judging from the stack you have a duplicate configuration. Did you only update the jars or did you do more? It looks like you also have put a `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation on a configuration class. Or have a too broad component-scan which picks up `org.springframework.batch` classes.

Comment: Thanks Luca & M. Deinum. The later answer (from M. Deinum) gave me the right direction. The new Spring batch program that I merged was done using Java Config, hence it has '@Configuration' & '@EnableBatchProcessing' annotations. I had to disable both the annotations to get this program working. 
What is the best way to get everything working without commenting? (Might be a very basic question, but I am very new to Spring Batch & Spring; Java Developer trying to catch up on new tech)

Comment: One more query to M. Deinum: What's the part in the log that provided you the intuition for this approach (Trying to learn from your expertise :) 
Honestly the stack trace deviated me from the real issue and I had spent a whole day in the direction of changing the JobBuilders, JobParameters etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps SimpleBatchConfiguration is already instantiating the jobRepository or associated elements, try taking them out of your context.